# Is sending a signal sending one bit of information?

Tags: unix, signals, information-theory

Descriptions of the traditional signal sending facility implemented in UNIX systems sometimes identify the action of ”sending a signal” with ”sending one bit of information.”  Is this identification accurate?

### Example of such a description

An example of such a description is provided by *Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment,* (W. Richard Stevens,Stephen A. Rago), where the description of the `sigqueue` function (**10.20**) claims that ”Generally a signal carries one bit of information: the signal itself.”

### Why a signal actually carries 0 bit of information

The signal has no state, so its state is described by 0 bits of information. What carries information is merely that a transmission actually occurred.

Sending 2 bits of information is the same as sending 2 times in a row 1 bit of information, so if a signal would convey 1 bit of information, we could send 2 bits of informations to a process by sending it two times (the same) signal, which looks impossible.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think *one bit of information* from the quote means literally one **bit** of information in information theory.

Here's my understanding. For a certain signal, there are only two possible states in a certain moment: a signal happens, or it doesn't happen. This binary states can be represented by one bit (`0` or `1`). By sending a signal to a process, this information is sent to it.

Again, I think you are overthinking this statement, after all, it's a book about programming, not information theory.

Comment: Of course, the only way “to make it right” is to put things like you do, nevertheless this is rather dissatisfying because when we transmit information, we usually do not take the transaction itself into the account of “information transmitted.”  Nevertheless it is useful to identify what may be just a poor wording in order to find better wordings when explaining these things.

Answer (score 1):

According to `man 2 kill`, the kill function takes `pid_t pid` and  `int sig` as parameters. So with kill, you can send information via the signal type (int) and that's it.

If you take a look at `man 2 sigaction`, it describes the information structure that you can handle in your signal handlers:

```
siginfo_t {
               int      si_signo;    /* Signal number */
               int      si_errno;    /* An errno value */
               int      si_code;     /* Signal code */
               int      si_trapno;   /* Trap number that caused
                                        hardware-generated signal
                                        (unused on most architectures) */
               pid_t    si_pid;      /* Sending process ID */
               uid_t    si_uid;      /* Real user ID of sending process */
               int      si_status;   /* Exit value or signal */
               clock_t  si_utime;    /* User time consumed */
               clock_t  si_stime;    /* System time consumed */
               sigval_t si_value;    /* Signal value */
               int      si_int;      /* POSIX.1b signal */
               void    *si_ptr;      /* POSIX.1b signal */
               int      si_overrun;  /* Timer overrun count; POSIX.1b timers */
               int      si_timerid;  /* Timer ID; POSIX.1b timers */
               void    *si_addr;     /* Memory location which caused fault */
               long     si_band;     /* Band event (was int in
                                        glibc 2.3.2 and earlier) */
               int      si_fd;       /* File descriptor */
               short    si_addr_lsb; /* Least significant bit of address
                                        (since Linux 2.6.32) */
           }
```

This would imply that you can send some additional info by choosing who (uid) you send the signal as and where from (pid -- you can tell if it is your child who's sending you the signal).

As for composing messages out of signal chains, that's theoretically possible, but you'd need to make sure your signal chain won't get randomly interrupted by another process (you can't prevent certain signal such as SIGKILL, but then, you're done when you receive a SIGKILL so no more translating message chains into ASCII or whatever :)

There's also sigqueue, which you can use to attach an integer to a signal you send (http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sigqueue.2.html), as I've learned in the following very good article on Linux signals:

http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sigqueue.2.html